# 2000+ элементов в ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Приложение UWP Windows 10.

Из базы данных грузиться группированный список (ObservableCollection), затем он присваивается как источник данных к CollectionView

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="Transactions"  IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

И само собой на форме имеется ListView следующего вида:

```
<ListView x:Name="TransactionsList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Transactions}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TransactionListViewTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
            ItemClick="TransactionsList_ItemClick">...
```

Суть вопроса - когда в списке больше тысячи элементов, отображение его в ListView занимает достаточно много времени (особенно на мобильном телефоне), после того как список отобразится то работает он с вполне приличной скоростью. Можно ли как то ускорить отображение списка в ListView не уменьшая количество загружаемых элементов (в теории их может быть 10К+)

Comment: Я бы попробовал что-то подобное - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

Comment: Не уверен что это можно применить к UWP, но спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего отмечу, что в UWP ListView поддерживает виртуализацию и она по умолчанию включена.

Коллекцию можно передать не полностью, а асинхронно "порциями". Таким образом, UI-поток не будет блокироваться и будет успевать отрисовать приходящие постепенно элементы.

Для базового примера заимплементил следующие классы:

```
public class Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

И переопределил у страницы метод `OnNavigatedTo`, в котором добавляю 1000 групп по 100 элементов:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var oc = new ObservableCollection<Group<Item>>();

        Transactions.Source = oc;

        var rand = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var group = new Group<Item>()
            {
                Key = rand.Next(1000).ToString()
            };

            await Task.Delay(100);

            oc.Add(group);

            for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                group.Add(new Item()
                {
                    Property1 = rand.Next(100000),
                    Property2 = rand.Next(100000)
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

`await Task.Delay(100);` просто ждет 100 миллисекунд, но делает это в другом потоке, тем самым освобождая UI-поток. В итоге имеем, что вся коллекция прогружается за несколько секунд, а в это время пользователь уже может свободно скроллить или каким-то другим способом взаимодействовать с прогруженным контентом. Очевидно, что этот подход можно всячески дополнять и менять под конкретную задачу.

Тем не менее в конкретно вашем случае предположу, что дело не только с отрисовке UI, но и в получении данных из БД. Насколько я понимаю, вы сначала ждете, пока БД отдаст все элементы, а только после этого принимаетесь за привязку к UI, что при тысячах записей и, вероятно, выполнении с ними промежуточных операций совершенно не эффективно. Поскольку БД преимущественно спроектированы таким образом, чтобы результатами их выдачи можно было пользоваться оп мере их поступления, то приведенный подход вполне можно распространить и на взаимодействие с БД. Удачи!

**Обновление от 05.04.2016:**
Вы скинули XAML-код своего DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TransactionListViewTemplate" x:DataType="data:Transaction">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="White">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <model:HideIfEmpty x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
                    <model:ShowArrow x:Key="transferConverter"/>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind displayTransTags}" Foreground="#FFF04137" FontSize="16" Margin="10,0,0,5" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="14" Height="14" Source="{Binding displayOutcomeAccountIcon}" Margin="10,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding displayOutcome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind displayOutcomeAccount}" FontSize="14" Margin="5,0,0,5" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding displayOutcome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE8CB;" FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding TransType, Converter={StaticResource transferConverter}}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="14" Height="14" Source="{Binding displayIncomeAccountIcon}" Margin="10,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding displayIncome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind displayIncomeAccount}" FontSize="14" Margin="5,0,0,5" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding displayIncome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind displayOutcome}" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,3,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding displayOutcome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind displayOutcomeInstrument}" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,20,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding displayOutcome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding TransType, Converter={StaticResource transferConverter}}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind displayIncome}" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,3,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding displayIncome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind displayIncomeInstrument}" FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,20,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="{Binding displayIncome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE707;" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding Payee, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Payee}" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="5,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding Payee, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE90A;" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="14" Margin="10,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding Comment, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Comment}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="5,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding Comment, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Начну с того, что Grid, StackPanel и конвертеры - вещи довольно "дорогие", особенно в списках, поэтому их использование стоит минимизировать.

В первую очередь нужно избавиться от корневого StackPanel, а свойства BorderThickness, BorderBrush и Background прописать в Grid.
Далее, можно избавиться от большинства StackPanel внутри Grid: бОльшую часть разметки можно выполнить с помощью `Grid.Row`, `Grid.Column` и `Grid.ColumnSpan`. Решил не переписывать код, а проиллюстрировать [картинкой](http://joxi.ru/v29WRqyiGkaZ4r.jpg).
Напоследок, в оставшихся StackPanel (у меня на изображении там, где тексты "text4 text5" и "text6 text7") вы у текстблоков на свойство Visibility вешаете идентичные конвертеры, а значит один код отрабатывает дважды. Просто повесьте конвертеры на свойство Visibility у соответствующих родительских StackPanel.

Тем не менее, и от использования оставшихся StackPanel можно уйти! Сделать это можно с помощью [RichTextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227565). Для примера переписал один из оставшихся StackPanel:

```
<RichTextBlock Margin="0 0 20 5"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               TextWrapping="NoWrap"
               Visibility="{Binding displayOutcome, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
     <RichTextBlock.Blocks>
         <Paragraph>
             <Run FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind displayOutcome}" />
             <Run FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind displayOutcomeInstrument}" />
         </Paragraph>
     </RichTextBlock.Blocks>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Кстати, на картинке выше для "text4 text5" я уже использую RichTextBlock. Как видите, разницы никакой, а производительности большой плюс =)

Дальше могу предложить копать в сторону отпимизации и упрощения ItemContainerStyle у ListView. Как найти стандартную реализацию и отредактировать ее копию под свои нужды можно прочитать и просмотреть в картинках в этой [статье (англ. яз.)](https://pcmusings.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/fixing-the-default-windows-8-xaml-itemcontainerstyle/)

Comment: Да вы правы. Проблема была именно в БД, перевел проект на SQLite и загрузка из БД занимает максимум пару секунд, отрисовывается все тоже достаточно быстро, однако если быстро листать список то можно увидеть темное мерцание на элементах списка, что очень не красиво. Во всех стандартных и сторонних приложениях на моем телефоне такого не наблюдается. Может есть какое нибудь решение?

Comment: @SYL, скиньте ItemTemplate у ListView

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Hiek7qPr

Comment: @SYL, обновил свой ответ. Дайте знать о результатах

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь.  Сегодня попробую и отпишусь о результате. У меня тут еще одни тупичек, посмотрите если не затруднит [stackoverflow] (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509862/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-uwp-databinding-%D0%B8-navigationcachemode)

Comment: Переделал шаблон http://pastebin.com/upHSDC6q - не знаю что я делаю не так, но по ощущениям стало хуже раза в 3. Теперь даже на ПК можно мерцание заметить если быстро скролить

Comment: Я полагаю проблема в автоматических размерах строк `Grid`. Если задать конкретный размер то все скролится хорошо, но выглядит ужасно из за кучи пустого места на половине элементов

Comment: @SYL, сейчас с временем сложно. Вам не нужно столько RichTextBlock, картинки могут лежать отдельно в нулевой колонке, загововок займет две колонки. Я не в курсе, какие изображения вы используете, но попробуйте применить технику, которую я вам описывал в другом вашем вопросе

Comment: @SYL, и еще раз напомню про ItemContainerStlye. В виртуализации элементы переиспользуются, ваш DataTemplate стал довольно "легким", очень сомневаюсь, что единственный Grid так долго перерисовывается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37975/discussion-between-artem-flotsky-and-syl).